# Is it possible to automatically show default jquery mobile ajax loader when I call $.post()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show Page Loading Spinner on Ajax Call in jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208609/show-page-loading-spinner-on-ajax-call-in-jquery-mobile)

Is it possible to automatically show default jquery-mobile ajax loader when I call $.post()

I.E. Set up some global config.

I saw this part of code in http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js

```
(function( $, window, undefined ) {

// jQuery.mobile configurable options
$.extend( $.mobile, {

    // Show loading message during Ajax requests
    // if false, message will not appear, but loading classes will still be toggled on html el
    loadingMessage: "loading",
```

But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208609/show-page-loading-spinner-on-ajax-call-in-jquery-mobile/12313138#12313138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Your code snippet sets the relevant `$.mobile` object property (i.e. the message you want to display). What you also need to do is trigger the loading event itself, which you can accomplish with this call:

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```