# Show Page Loading Spinner on Ajax Call in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using $.ajax() to populate a list in my mobile web app. What I'd like to do is have the jQuery mobile loading spinner appears while this call is being performed and disappear once the list populates. The current version of JQM uses `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` and `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()` to show and hide the loading spinner, respectively. I can't figure out where exactly to place these statements to get the correct result. This seems like it should be a fairly easy thing to accomplish, I just haven't been able to find anything about this exact scenario.

Here's the ajax call inside the pagecreate function:

```
$('#main').live('pagecreate', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: //url
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: //headers
            success: function(data) {
                for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#courses').append('<li>' + data[i].name + '<ul id="course' + data[i].id + '"></ul>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + data[i].evaluatedUserIds.length + '</span></li>');
                    $('#course' + data[i].id).listview();
                    for(j = 0; j < data[i].evaluatedUserIds.length; j++) {
                        $('#course' + data[i].id).append('<li><a href="">' + data[i].evaluatedUserIds[j] + '</a></li>');
                    }
                    $('#course' + data[i].id).listview('refresh');
                }
                $('#courses').listview('refresh');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A few people have asked about the workaround I ended up implementing, so I figured I'd share it. It's nothing particularly elegant or complicated, but it did seem to work. I haven't used the framework since the official 1.0 was released, so this may have been solved in the update. Essentially, I put the `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` call into the `pageshow` function, but wrapped it in an if clause that only fires the first time the page is shown:

```
var mainloaded = false;

$('#main').live('pageshow', function(event) {   //Workaround to show page loading on initial page load
    if(!mainloaded) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    }
});

$('#main').live('pagecreate', function(event) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: //url
        dataType: //datatype,
        headers: //headers
        success: function(data) {
            //
            //...loading stuff
            //
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            mainloaded = true;
        }
        //
        //...handle error, etc.
        //
    });
});
```

Comment: you are correct about moving the show from the pagecreate event, since right after this event JQM calls hidePageLoadingMsg since the page loading has finished (and this overrides your call)

Answer (score 58):

You can use the `beforeSend` and `complete` events of `$.ajax` to call `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg` and `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg`. Would look like this:

```
$('#main').live('pagecreate', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }, //Show spinner
            complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() }, //Hide spinner
            url: //url
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: //headers
            success: function(data) {
                //...
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I also tried this at first, but it doesn't seem to work either. The ajax call is happening inside the pagecreate function. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: tried that too. no such luck. i'm not sure what's going on, bug perhaps? ultimately, it's not that big of a deal for the moment.

Comment: Try replacing the `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();` by an alert.

Comment: Either `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` isn't working or your JSON request is so fast you don't see the spinner appearing.

Comment: Its working. And i guess its the correct way of doing it. thanks Xeon06.

Comment: @Xeon06 just add a semicolon after $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()

Comment: Worked for me instantly. Thanks for saving time and posting precise, compact and working code.

Answer (score 50):

Before JQM 1.2:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

Since JQM 1.2:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

http://api.jquerymobile.com/page-loading/

Comment: I am using jQueryMobile 1.1 and implemented    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); and then $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); but it only worked on firefox... it doesnt do anything on chrome or my safari.. any ideas why?

Comment: Is there an output in console?

Comment: This is a fantastic solution!  Prevents coding (or potentially forgetting) to show the spinner on every AJAX call.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit late...but you need to:

1. Call `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` before the AJAX call.
2. Make the AJAX call. **The call needs to be sent asynchronously** (put `async: true` in your call).
3. Add `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()` in your `success()` function.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what other people said, and also the first thing I tried. The conclusion I came to was that there was a bug in the version of the beta I was using that was causing the loading message to not be displayed upon initial page load. I ended up finding a workaround. Thanks anyway, for the response.

Comment: @Sean, I seem to have the same problem you described. Could you please provide me the workaround you've found? Thank you

Comment: what happens if you need the call to be async = false?

Comment: was searching for this answer for hours!

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
    $.mobile.loading( 'show');
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $.mobile.loading( 'hide');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do **$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()** just before the ajax call, and **$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()** in the success (or fail) block so it goes away once a result comes back.

I've never used jQuery mobile, but it should operate the same as showing/hiding a regular ol' spinning image.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've tried leaving out the hide call to see if the show call was working at all (instead of going away too quickly to see), but no such luck.

Answer (score 3):

**Or, the simplest way is to put it globally as a separation of concern -**

Put below code into your master/layout view

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
        //Loader settings
        $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "Loading..";
        $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = true;
        $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "b";
        $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textonly = false; 
    }); 

    $(document).on({
        ajaxSend: function () { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); },
        ajaxStart: function () { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); },
        ajaxStop: function () { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); },
        ajaxError: function () { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); }
    });

</script>
```

Edit: Please use instead if you are targeting latest version of JQM (>1.2):

- $.mobile.loading('show');
- $.mobile.loading('hide');

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the call to $.ajax() happens within the control flow of the event handler (the caller).

A very simple way to decouple the ajax request from this control flow is to let setTimeout() invoke this function for you, like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){$.ajax( ... )}, 1);
```

You can then use the 'beforeSend' and 'complete' events of $.ajax() as stated before and be sure, that your spinner is showing up.