# Show Page Loader (Spinner) on Ajax Call in jQuery Mobile 1.3

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 app that is making Ajax calls to dynamically load data. I have seen various options for doing this in previous versions of jQuery Mobile (see [Show Page Loading Spinner on Ajax Call in jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208609/show-page-loading-spinner-on-ajax-call-in-jquery-mobile)), but have not found an answer for 1.3.

The Ajax calls are similar to:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  $.each(data.cards, function(index, card) {
    $('#card-name').text(card.title);
  });
});
```

What is the best approach for displaying the loading spinner for each Ajax call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research and trying several options, I found that this worked well for every Ajax call in the app. I added the following code toward the top of my JavaScript:

```
// Load the spinner if an ajaxStart occurs; stop when it is finished
$(document).on({
  ajaxStart: function() { 
    $.mobile.loading('show');
  },
  ajaxStop: function() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
  }    
});
```

In this way, no matter how many places I load data via Ajax, the jQuery Mobile loader (spinner) is displayed by adding this snippet of code one time.

If anyone knows of a better approach, please let me know.